# MapServer ESRI personal geodabase.mdb

Tags: gdal, mapserver, esri-geodatabase

I'm trying to read ESRI personal geodabase.mdb through OGR. I have my driver "PGeo" but when I write

> ogrinfo INFLOR090812.mdb

I have this bug:

`ERROR 1: Unable to initialize ODBC connection to DSN for DRIVER=Microsoft Access
 Driver (*.mdb);DBQ=INFLOR090812.mdb,
[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Could not find file '(unknown)'.
ERROR 1: Unable to initialize ODBC connection to DSN for DRIVER=Microsoft Access
 Driver (*.mdb);DBQ=INFLOR090812.mdb,
[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Could not find file '(unknown)'.`

Someone could connect to a database.mdb to read the shapefiles in MapServer?

Comment: did you read through everything on the ogr ESRI Personal Geodatabase format page? http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_pgeo.html

Answer (score 1):

As noted in a comment by [neuhausr](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/1199/neuhausr) there is a documented solution for this problem on the GDAL site [GDAL info page for ESRI Personal GeoDatabase](http://www.gdal.org/drv_pgeo.html), but the solution is only for Linux.

If like me you find yourself on a 64-bit Windows platform and have 64-bit MapServer/GDAL you might find yourself scratching your head, as yes you can get the same error :-(

> msDrawMap(): Image handling error. Failed to draw layer named 'OGE_1M_surface_GeologicUnit'. msOGRFileOpen(): OGR error. Open failed for OGR connection in layer `OGE_1M_surface_GeologicUnit'. Unable to initialize ODBC connection to DSN for DRIVER=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb);DBQ=C:/WxS/ms/apps/published/BGS_OGE_Bedrock_and_Surface_Geology/data2/OGE.mdb, [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

For me the solution was as follows:

Download/install the 64-bit version of the ODBC driver: [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=13255)

Now in your MapServer map file you need to add the following two CONFIG options:

```
CONFIG "PGEO_DRIVER_TEMPLATE" "DRIVER=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb);DBQ=%s"
CONFIG "OGR_SKIP" "ODBC"
```

These config options are discussed in [GDAL bug 5594 ~ Problem reading MDBs (64-bit)](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/5594)