# Opening Esri Geodatabase file with GDAL/QGIS/Grass?

Tags: qgis, r, grass-gis, file-geodatabase

EDIT: I have a 64-bit installation of QGIS but 32-bit Microsoft Office Access drivers. It has been suggested that this is the cause of the problem, which is also indicated in this post:
https://www.sigterritoires.fr/index.php/en/access-an-esri-personal-geodatabase-with-qgis-2-18-or-3-0/

I tried installing 64-bit drivers but installer says I have to uninstall Office to do this. If anyone knows a workaround or could verify that the file opens in QGIS with 64-bit drivers that would be great.

---

ORIGINAL POST

I am trying to import the Oceania dataset of the Global Drainage Basin Database into GIS:
http://www.cger.nies.go.jp/db/gdbd/gdbd_index_e.html

I have tried:

1. rgdal::readOGR in R (most recent canonical version, GDAL version 2.2.3)
2. v.in.ogr in Grass GIS 7.6.1
3. Data Source Manager in QGIS 3.6.1

All of these result in an error message: "Cannot open data source" / "ERROR: Unable to open data source [filename]" / "Invalid Data Source".

I have followed steps described in previous answers to questions about importing this file format to QGIS on StackExchange and haven't been able to find a solution. Any approach that lets me convert into a more universally accepted format would work.

Running Windows 10.

Comment: There are two strong possibilities: 1) It's corrupt 2) It's a 9.x FGDB, unreadable by the FGDB API

Comment: On the download page reads `The file is in ArcGIS Geodatabase (Version 9) format` and ogrinfo prints `Unable to initialize ODBC connection to DSN for DRIVER=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb);DBQ=oceania.mdb` for me.

Comment: Are you running 64bit qgis and do you have the 64bit odbc drivers installed https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/138445/2856

Comment: Others have been able to open the files; not corrupt.

Comment: It seems I'm unable to install 64-bit ODBC drivers for Microsoft Access (.mdb) because my employer-provided Microsoft Office version is 32-bit Office 2010. (Or well unable to install without uninstalling Office.) I'll try asking someone with 64-bit drivers to open and save to a less barbaric format, thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

In v2 of Q you can add it in as a File/System vector layer:

[image]

I would suspect you can do this in v3 too.